# Else Statement is a syntax error?

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error

My code is probably amateur to a lot of you, so if any of my logic in it is messed up, that's okay. I'll fix that later. Just wondering if anyone could let me know why my else statement is coming up with: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Syntax error on token "else", delete this token"

I read some of the other questions on here and usually the problem is people are checking conditions (else (blah < bleh) {) with else, but I didn't do that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class minOfThree {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        int num1, num2, num3, num4, min = 0;

        System.out.println ("Please enter three numbers.");
        System.out.print ("First value: ");
        num1=kb.nextInt();
        System.out.print ("Second value: ");
        num2=kb.nextInt();
        System.out.print ("Third value: ");
        num3=kb.nextInt();
        System.out.print ("Fourth value: ");
        num4=kb.nextInt();

        if (num1 < num2)
            if (num1 < num3)
                min=num1;
            else
                min=num3;
        else if (num2 < num3)
                min=num2;
            else
                min = num3;
        ***else*** {
            min = num4;
        }
        System.out.println ("Minimum value is: " + min);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `else` that causes the error doesn't seem to have a corresponding `if`.

Comment: You really should use braces. Especially if you're getting errors like this.

Comment: Alright. Yeah, I got a bit sloppy with that. I fixed it but got another error or two. Working on it now though. Thanks!

Comment: Never omit braces. Never. I know you can. In know some C idioms use it. But if you always use braces and always indent properly, you'll avoid a lot of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get into the habit of always writing if-else statements within brackets, then you will never have to wonder what statement goes with which test. I believe the following is what you want your code to look like:

```
if (num1 < num2) {
    if (num1 < num3) {
        min = num1;
    } else {
        min = num3;
    }
} else {
    if (num2 < num3) {
        min = num2;
    } else {
        min = num3;
    }
} else {
    min = num4;
}
```

Although that does not make full sense because here you get two `else`s as well.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I tend to get a little sloppy with code sometimes. Thanks!

Comment: I know it is difficult to second guess what the OP wanted, but I'm not sure posting syntactically invalid code is a great idea. Prehaps combine the middle `else` into the if (making it `else if(num2 < num3)`...)

Answer (score 8):

This could have been avoided if you used `{` and `}` properly:

```
if(num1 < num2) //"if" for if-else #1
{
    if(num1 < num3) //"if" for if-else #2
    {
        min=num1;
    }
    else //"else" for if-else #2
    {
        min=num3;
    } //complete end of if-else #2
}
else if(num2 < num3) //"else if" for if-else #1
{
    min=num2;
}
else //"else" for if-else #1
{
    min = num3;
} //complete end of if-else #1
else //"else" for nonexistent if-else == error
{
    min = num4;
}
```

Here you can see that you have two `else`s on one if-else statement.

To fix it, use something like this:

```
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //minimum = maximum possible
if(num1 < min) //if num1 is less than current minimum...
{
    min = num1; //current minimum = num1
}
if(num2 < min) //if num2 is less than current minimum...
{
    min = num2; //current minimum = num2
}
if(num3 < min) //if num3 is less than current minimum...
{
    min = num3; //current minimum = num3
}
if(num4 < min) //if num4 is less than current minimum...
{
    min = num4; //current minimum = num4
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There can only be one else for each if/else if. The `else if (num2 < num3)` part already has an `else` statement two lines below it. Maybe you are missing an if-statement somewhere?

Comment: Are you talking about the formatting? Because it isn't inside the else if statement. Unless I'm just misunderstanding what you're saying. It looks like the asterisks make it look like it's inside the else if statement.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the code itself, not the formatting. Have a closer look at the part I pointed out. The `else` I told you about already  terminates the top-level if-statement. There is no matching `if` for the `***else***`.

Answer (score 3):

If it were me, I would just use braces and move on ;-)

```
if () {
  // hack
} else if () {
  // hack hack
} else {
  // hack hack
}
```

However, the logic you use is wrong, too, you could replace your last else by

```
if (min > num4) {
  min = num4; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It happens because the `else if` doesn't create a new if/else branch. This is the correct indentation of how compiler interprets it.

```
    if (num1 < num2)
        if (num1 < num3)
            min=num1;
        else
            min=num3;
    else if (num2 < num3)
        min=num2;
    else
        min = num3;
    else
        min = num4;
```

As you can see, it is not what you intended. So, as only one `else` statement is allowed, it doesn't compile. As already suggested, you should use braces.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! This made a lot of sense and I instantly fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Just got the power to upvote yesterday. Doing so now!

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge if you are not writing multiple lines inside a scope (i.e. if-else statment), then there is not required of `{}`.

```
if (num1 < num2)              //1st If Start
        if (num1 < num3)          //2nd If Start
            min=num1;
        else
            min=num3;             //2nd If Ends
    else if (num2 < num3)         //3rd If starts in else part of 1st If
            min=num2;
        else
            min = num3;           //3rd If Ends
    ***else*** {              //This else part is not followed by any If Statement (Causes Error )
        min = num4;
    }
```

In this case your approach is correct but, you missed the start point of this last else.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is amateur but it's ok? You are using two Else statements. That makes no sense. And you don't have brackets encapsulating the routines which is really confusing. What are you even trying to do? Are you trying to find the smallest number? Try this?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int num1 = 4;
    int num2 = 2;
    int num3 = 3;
    int num4 = 10;

    int array[] = {num1, num2, num3, num4};

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] > array [j+1])
            {
                int x = array[j];
                array[j] = array [j+1];
                array [j+1] = x;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case yes because there's no sense of a second else clause. It would be unreachable code

Answer (score 1):

Look at the first if statement. You didn't put the braces and other mistakes you made. like putting two else statements to one if statement.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOver {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
            int num1, num2, num3, num4, min = 0;

            System.out.println ("Please enter three numbers.");
            System.out.print ("First value: ");
            num1=kb.nextInt();
            System.out.print ("Second value: ");
            num2=kb.nextInt();
            System.out.print ("Third value: ");
            num3=kb.nextInt();
            System.out.print ("Fourth value: ");
            num4=kb.nextInt();

            if (num1 < num2){
                if (num1 < num3)
                    min=num1;
                else
                    min=num3;
            }else if (num2 < num3)
                min=num2;
            else if(num4 < num3)
                min = num4;
            else
                min = num3;
            System.out.println ("Minimum value is: " + min);
        }
}
```